# GameCenter Notifications Obtrusive to iAd view

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, iad, gamekit

I am displaying an iAd Banner at the top of my game and game center notifications are covering the iAd. Is there any GameKit framework delegate code that will let me know when a GameCenter banner is sliding onto my view so I can also slide my iAd down and then back up so the advertisement isn't covered.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no delegate method that notifies you when a Game Center banner will appear. Also keep in mind that what you're trying to do can disturb the user's game experience. I can tell you from personal experience that ads are pretty useless when users don't play your game regularly. 'Less is more' definitely applies to the implementation of mobile ads.

However, there are some methods/properties that can disable the game center banners. This gives you the opportunity to create your own custom Game Center UI. This information be found in Apple's Game Center Programming Guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html .

Keep in mind that this is no small undertaking. You'll have to handle all the Game Center features, like achievements and challenges, separately. But it's your best shot at handling the obtrusiveness of Game Center notifications.

If you don't want to write your own Game Center UI, consider placing your iAd banner at the bottom in parts where the notifications are most intrusive.

Comment: Thankyou! I will leave the question open for a few more days, maybe someone knows of some APIs or Frameworks that already handle this, or clever NSTimers that can check for new UIViews dropping in to a *.superview.superview.superview etc hahah! After which point I will accept your answer if they haven't come forward! (Just set a reminder on my phone! Thanks again)